# Spring load a file

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee

I need to load a file from within a directory in the root of a WAR using Spring
This is the directory structure

```
rootOfWar
--static-dir
---- my-file.css
--WEB-INF
---- classes
.....
```

It is a normal WAR.

In a Spring @RestController I need to be able to read and write to my-file.css file.  What is the best way to get the File, ServletContextResource or?

**More Details**
 - The location of the file is out of my control I cannot move the file.
 - The jee container is Tomcat.
 - The Spring version is current 4.1.6
 - The Spring environment is not using XML only annotations with WebApplicationInitializer, WebMvcConfigurerAdapter and an annotation configuration class.

Is there another way to do this like specify a file as a resource in the configuration so that it is loaded by the frame work and accessible within the application?

Basically I have JEE knowledge but my Spring knowledge on best practices concerning read/write are lacking.

Comment: You can't write into a WAR file. (Well, I mean you *can*, but not in the way it seems like you want to.)

Comment: @DaveNewton Normally I would use the classpath and write to that, which you can, but I do not have the option in this instance, the structure is out of my control. If it can only be done with a ServletContextResource then I guess that is the answer. I was told that Spring had other options to achieve a read/write in the WAR other than using the ServletContext. How would you do it in the way that you describe it *can* be done

Comment: Keep it in the database, maybe?

Comment: Thanks for the respones @DaveNewton  as I say I do not have the control over this structure it is defined by someone else. It could be a flat file database also ;-).  But either way I cannot move this file. So I presume using the ServletContextResource in Spring is the only way to load this file then? It does work like that rear/write relative to the WAR root FYI.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to modify a file you should not make it part of the WAR. Store it somewhere outside the web package and reference it there. Everything else will lead to problems, especially when you deploy to Websphere which is often run in a restricted environment where writes are rejected.

But I consider overwriting files in the web path bad design, because you are likely to run into caching issues. Better write a servlet that generates the CSS you need. If you would be able to name the content that should overwrite your css file, you are also able to render this dynamically.

Something like this may be already sufficient:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/my.css", produces = "text/css;charset=UTF-8")
public String showCss() {
    return "<here goes your css>";
}
```

(This is written from my memory and not tested).

The good thing is that you can modify the css any time you want and even set caching information as needed.

Comment: hello, thanks for the response. This is a controlled soft appliance environment Tomcat. For WebSphere you need to add a WAS policy file and then you can control where you want to write to. For WAS clusters using the configuration directory of the deployment manager is something you can do to ensure all nodes are synchronised. The file is stored in the WAR I have no control over this. The application that manages (writes) to the CSS file is not the same as the one that reads it.

Comment: @Gurnard If I had known these details at the time I wrote my answer that answer would have been different ;-) When your question does not contain all the details needed to find a solution that matches your requirements, how are we to give answers that fit ? I assume the downvote is not yours ?

Comment: I have updated my question to be more full I was trying to avoid sounding like a discussion and more like a direct question as I know that is the purpose of SO. I agree this is bad design but that I have no power over.